# KSH: How to escape backslash and double quotes together

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I can't force KSH to pass `\"` as a parameter to command.
What I want to be executed LITERALLY is:

```
command \"foo bar\"
```

Below examples are executed in ksh with set -x executed beforehand to display the echo of each command in the exact format in which it would be executed (after it is parsed by ksh)

```
[oracle@localhost sf_vm]$ ksh
$ set -x
```

What I tried and got is:

```
$ command \"foo bar\"
+ command '"foo' 'bar"'
```

not what I need: missing \ and additional ' and "

```
$ command \\\"foo bar\\\"
+ command '\"foo' 'bar\"'
```

no luck again: additional ' outside and between foo and bar

```
$ command "\\\"foo bar\\\""
+ command '\"foo bar\"'
```

almost right but still unwanted ' on the outside

```
$ command '\"foo bar\"'
+ command '\"foo bar\"'
```

again almost right but still ' on the outside

The actual use case is that I'm passing USERID parameter to oracle expdb command in format of
`expdp USERID=/ AS SYSDBA` which needs to be enclosed in escaped double quotes like so:

```
expdp USERID=\"/ AS SYSDBA\"
```

I know I can workaround this by using a prm file for expdp but it's very inconvenient in my case (automated export)

I'm using ksh93 version if that makes any difference:

```
[oracle@localhost sf_vm]$ ll /etc/alternatives/ksh
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Oct 15  2018 /etc/alternatives/ksh -> /bin/ksh93
```

Comment: What `set -x` logs is a _human-readable representation_ of what it passes to your command. The *actual data* is an array of C strings; it has to be escaped to become human-readable.

Comment: So, when you say you want to execute `command \"foo bar\"`, what _exactly_ is the array of C strings you want that to execute? Because what I would expect that to run is the array -- expressed in JSON format -- `["command", "\"foo", "bar\""]`. Is that the array you want to use?

Comment: (To be clear: `command '"foo' 'bar"'` is valid shell syntax for an argv that aligns with the JSON string `["command", "\"foo", "bar\""]`, which is to say, the shell is _telling you that it did what you asked for_, and you're just misunderstanding the syntax it used for that).

Comment: By contrast, if what you want is `command "foo bar"`, then _don't use the backslashes_. When they're left out the double quotes are treated as syntax rather than literal data.

Comment: Thank you Charles, what you pointed out allowed me the find the real root cause of my problem as I described in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from your use case.

The following command, which you assert works

```
expdp USERID=\"/ AS SYSDBA\"
```

evaluates to a rather unintuitive argument list, as you can see below (note that this particular code only works for argument lists that don't contain literal newlines anywhere):

```
$ printf '%s\n' expdp USERID=\"/ AS SYSDBA\" | jq -Rnc '[inputs]'
["expdp","USERID=\"/","AS","SYSDBA\""]
```

...which is to say, you're passing `expdp` three arguments beyond the 0th/first one: `USERID="/` is the first argument, `AS` is the second argument, and `SYSDBA"` is the third argument. The shell is correct when its `set -x` implementation prints this argument list as `expdp 'USERID="/' AS 'SYSDBA"'`, as that argument list eval's identically to the above.

Frankly, I doubt very much that this is actually correct/intended usage for any tool. It would make more sense if your backslashes weren't escaped, and your intended usage were instead `expdp USERID="/ AS SYSDBA"`, which would evaluate to (in JSON syntax) `["expdp", "USERID=/ AS SYSDBA"]`.

Comment: The syntax of the expdp is as follows expdp PARAM1=VALUE1 PARAM2=VALUE2 and so on. It works just fine when the VALUE doesn't have spaces. When the VALUE have spaces it should be enclosed with double qutoes i.e PARAM="VALUE WITH SPACE" but that doesn't seem to work in ksh

Comment: Quotes in all POSIX-flavored shells (not just ksh) set character-by-character parse flags that prevent string-splitting and globbing from taking place (and for single quotes, also prevent various other operations as well). So when you run `PARAM="VALUE WITH SPACE"` in a POSIX-y shell, it just becomes `PARAM=VALUE WITH SPACE`, but with the spaces suppressed from being able to split apart the string into multiple arguments (so in JSON, it would make things `["PARAM=VALUE WITH SPACE"]` instead of `["PARAM=VALUE", "WITH", "SPACE"]` as you'd have without any quotes).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to your comments about the set -x which I did interpreted wrongly I got it actually working with `command \"foo bar\"` besides what the set output would suggest it correctly passes the "foo bar" enclosed with brackets as a command paramater.

As it turned out my actual issue was the syntax in the parameter value itself.
For future reference following expdp command syntax is correct in ksh when value begin passed has spaces (in this case userid as sysdba):

```
expdp USERID=\"sys/password@SID as sysdba\" DIRECTORY=EXPDP DUMPFILE=HR.COUNTRIES.dmp TABLES=HR.COUNTRIES ...
```